# Как задокументровать собственные свойства объекта, имена которых генерируются во время выполнения конструктора класса

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Итак, допустим у нас имеется некоторый код:

```js
/**
 * Object implementation of the matrix.
 *
 * @class Table
 */
class Table {

    /**
     * Creates an instance of Table.
     *
     * @param {Array.<number[]>} matrix - Inital matrix
     *
     * @memberof Table
     */
    constructor(matrix) {

      matrix.forEach((row, rowNum, matrix) => {
        this[rowNum] = [];

        matrix.forEach((value, colNum, row) => {
          this[rowNum][colNum] = new Cell(value);
        })
      })

      debugger
    }
  }

  /**
   * Object implementation of the matrix cell.
   *
   * @class Cell
   */
  class Cell {

    /**
     * Creates an instance of Cell.
     * @param {number} value
     *
     * @memberof Cell
     */
    constructor(value) {
      // Some code
    }
  }


  let table = new Table([
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0]
  ]);

  console.log(table);
```

Если вызвать конструктор класса `Table`, он вернет объект с произвольным количеством свойств, имена которых являются числами от 0 до размерности входной матрицы. Значением каждого такого свойства будет массив значений типа `{Cell}`.

Как объяснить это интерпретатору JSDoc?

Честно говоря даже мыслей нет, с какой стороны взяться.

Comment: Да на самом деле никак. Но можно в описании класса словами описать, как составляются поля объекта.

Comment: Примерно так и предполагал сделать, но вдруг произойдет чудо и кто-нибудь придумает хитрый финт. ))

Comment: [Can JSDoc document dynamically generated methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36042060/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy, виртуальный комментарий я уже рассматривал - метод хороший, но задачу решает не полностью. Проблема в том, что количество свойств произвольно. По сути, вопрос можно переформулировать: как описать произвольное количество однотипных свойств, имена которых генерируются по некоторому шаблону.